# Interop communication between managed and native code deprecated in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I got this message from one of our vendors explaining that they are going to remove support for their Interop libraries because:

> Interop based communication between managed and native code was
>   deprecated starting with .NET 4.0

Is this correct? If so, what is the proper way and why? I can't fathom why it is a bad idea to manage a COM object from an Interop. Microsoft does this as far as I remember with all their Office products.

Comment: What kind of interop?

Comment: I don't think such a statement holds true. Perhaps they plan to deprecate it within their product suite.

Comment: Tell them to provide you MSDN link that stated that.

Comment: In your quote they don't actually say **MS** deprecated it starting with .NET 4.0. Ask who has deprecated it. It's probably the vendor.

Comment: Oh, this vendor is going to get a beating from us :-)

Comment: @RegEdit: I guess you could read it that way but I sure didn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is going to require reading tea-leaves, you most definitely ought to contact the vendor and ask for details.  But sure, something important happened in .NET 4.0, it no longer requires **shipping** interop libraries.  Microsoft Office doesn't anymore either, starting with Office 2013.

Very elegantly solved in VS2010 and .NET 4.0 with the new "Embed Interop Types" feature.  Also known as the "No PIA" feature.  The option is turned on automatically when you add a reference to the type library.  The effect is as though you had declared all of the interop types in your own source code.  Just the ones you use.  Particularly effective for Office interop libraries, they are very large.

The underlying change in the v4 CLR that powers this feature is new way to check for type identity.  Specific to [ComImport] types, two types are considered identical when they have the same [Guid].  The assemblies they came from is no longer important.  This obsoletes the need for PIAs.

You probably have to change your workflow slightly, now picking the reference from the COM tab.  Perhaps a small change in your source code if you were previously in the habit of creating the XxxxClass object, you simply edit it to create the Xxxx interface instead.  And change the installer project, no need to copy the DLL(s) anymore.

All and all, COM interop is **significantly** improved in .NET 4.0, particularly the changes in the C# language make it *much* easier to use.  A million miles away from imminent death :)

So the vendor is probably telling you that they are not going to ship the interop libraries anymore.  Because you don't need them anymore.  If you have no idea what the type library looks like then ask the vendor for help.

Comment: Yes, they have a type library and this is what they are pushing. But if someone doesn't have their product installed the type library reference won't work but with the Interop anyone could compile, they just won't be able to run. This becomes a problem when this project is included in a CI environment or in a large solution that others may use.

Comment: Sure, there's very little consideration for programmers that write code that they cannot test.  Still not a problem, you can simply run Tlbimp.exe on a machine that has the product installed.  That produces an interop library too.  Not recommended of course, easy to end up with stale libraries that way.  And you can't test.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN still has documented support for Interop. Here is a link on [Interop Marshalling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), note that it is documented for .net 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Either they interpreted a MSDN resource incorrect, read a painfully wrong blog post, don't want to support interop anymore or you misunderstood them.

That claim is incorrect anyway, ask them for a credible source.

Answer (score 1):

There are four kinds of unmanaged interop in .NET, and AFAIK none of them has been deprecated so far:

- COM interop
- Platform Invoke (P/Invoke), i.e. `[DllImport]`
- "It Just Works" interop (just for C++ / C++/CLI)
- WinRT interop, i.e. referencing a `.winmd` metadata file from your project (starting with Windows 8 / Visual Studio 2012 / .NET 4.5)

[This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx), which is talking about Visual Studio 2013, mentions the first three in present tense; there's no hint whatsoever that any of these interop mechanisms is being deprecated. And the last one (Windows Runtime interop) was just recently introduced.